# Report structure from table

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a large project with a lot of reports, but the items in the reports are quite standard, reusable with parameters. So I've made subreports, that's OK. Now I assemble the reports by adding subreports to them by hand, plus setting the parameters, also by hand.

I think that this is not flexible enough, I'd like to have a table that defines the structure of the report: like one row per subreport, specifying the name and its parameter values. Then the report would be assembled together runtime in a list or something like that, by calling and inserting the subreport by name.

Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way to dynamically assemble a report like that without coding something that would generate the required RDL, upload it to the report server and then execute the report.

Another option might be to create one master report with all possible subreports in it. You could then use a table to control the visibility of each subreport, to simulate generating different reports. Obviously you don't want to execute long running queries for subreports that are hidden, so you would have to add a parameter to all your subreports so that if the subreport is hidden the dataset returns no data, e.g.

```
WHERE
(....) OR (@SubReportHidden = 'Hidden' AND 1=0)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've met the second idea somewhere here in another thread but actually I don't really like it. The first one seems to be somewhat better but I'm looking for something like an SSRS API that you could use for that with some custom coding in ASP.NET, for example.